# text search function in excel (or VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Outstanding report as of 06 Feb 2013.xls

tbk_report-itm-status_20130207.csv

tbk_report-tscm-status_20130207_0620.csv

TEC Log template 2.1 (February 13).xls

TSOM_SLA_daily_20130207.xls

Data outstanding ticket report as of 6 February 2013.xls

mnr_report-itm-status_20130207.csv

mnr_report-tscm-status_20130207.csv

isd_report-itm-status_20130207.csv

isd_report-tscm-status_20130207.csv
```

this is the list of file in table at column C

in column A1 I want to search text in column C that contains "tbk" and "tscm"

then in A1 will be like "tbk_report-tscm-status_20130207_0620.csv"

What function should I use?

I know it easy question but I have try mix formula by myself but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("tbk*tscm*",C:C,0))
```

Note that this will match
`tbk_blah-tscm-blah`
but not
`tscm-blah-tbk-blah`

Comment: VLOOKUP would also do the job, `=VLOOKUP("tbk*tscm*",C:C,1,0)`